# ¿Cómo identificar un tipo de usuario y que me mande a su perfil?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

estoy desarrollando una plataforma que conecta maestros con alumnos, ya he creado mi login y sign up, pero al momento de que inicie sesión, necesito que dependiendo del tipo de usuario me mande al perfil del maestro o alumno.

En mi tabla tengo los datos de cada uno y una columna extra que se llama "TipoUsuario".
1 = Maestro
2 = Alumno

En el formulario del alumno tengo:

```
<?php
include('classes/DB.php');
if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $genero = $_POST['genero'];
        $FDia = $_POST['FDia'];
        $FMes = $_POST['FMes'];
        $FAnio = $_POST['FAnio'];
        $TipoUsuario = 2;

        if(!DB::query('SELECT email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$email))) {

if(strlen($password) >= 6 && strlen($password) <= 60){


        DB::query('INSERT INTO registroalumnos VALUES (null, :name, :email, :password, :genero, :FDia, :FMes, :FAnio, :TipoUsuario)',array(':name'=>$name, ':email'=>$email, ':password'=>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), ':genero'=>$genero, ':FDia'=>$FDia, ':FMes'=>$FMes, ':FAnio'=>$FAnio, ':TipoUsuario'=>$TipoUsuario));
        echo "Success!";

      } else{
        echo 'Contraseña no valida';

      }


} else {
        echo 'Correo ya registrado!';

      }
}
?>
```

Y en el formulario del maestro tengo exactamente lo mismo, solo que mi variable de $TipoUsuario le puse el valor de 1.

Ahora, hice un archivo .php para el perfil, solo que aun no le asigno si es para maestro o alumno, que es lo que me falta.

Este es mi código de perfil:

```
<?php
include('classes/DB.php');
include('login.php');

 $name="";
 $email="";
 $isFollowing = False;

 if (isset($_GET['email'])){


    if(DB::query('SELECT name, email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']))){

         $name = DB::query('SELECT name, email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']))[0]['name'];
         $email = DB::query('SELECT email FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']))[0]['email'];
         $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM registroalumnos WHERE email=:email', array(':email'=>$_GET['email']))[0]['id'];
                        $followerid = login::isLoggedIn();


                if (isset($_POST['follow'])) {

                    if($userid != $followerid){

                        if (!DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid, AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid))){
                               DB::query('INSERT INTO followers VALUES (null, :userid, :followerid)', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                        } else {
                                echo 'Ya lo sigues!';
                        }

                        $isFollowing = True;
                    }
                }


     if (isset($_POST['unfollow'])) {
                        if ($userid != $followerid) {
                                if (DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid))) {

                                        DB::query('DELETE FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                                }
                                $isFollowing = False;
                        }
                }
                if (DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid))) {
                        //echo 'Ya lo sigues!';
                        $isFollowing = True;
                }


    }else {
        die('Usuario no encontrado');
    }
 } 


?>
```

Más que nada es un ejemplo donde hasta viene la opción de seguir usuarios.

Pero me pregunto si hago dos archivos de perfil.php para cada uno, o con solo uno basta?, pensaba que con un "if" dependiendo del perfil.

Gracias.

Comment: Yo también lo haría con un if en una misma página, te ahorras trabajo en cambios futuros, aunque depende mucho del proyecto.

Comment: Realmente no me queda claro cual es el problema. En principio no veo necesidad de crear 2 archivos que harán lo mimos, y lo único que varía es un dato (tipo usuario). Intenta desarrollar un poco más tu pregunta.